# Removing certain XML lines from staging in git

Tags: xml, git

I tried following another SO question that used *.rb inside gitattributes. That didn't seem to work (either I'm not doing my regex correctly or sed doesn't follow my regex...), but does anyone have a full solution to this?

Say I had the following lines:

```
<note>
<!-- gitignore -->
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<!-- gitignore -->
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I want to get rid of the two comments and everything in between them so that they aren't staged. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's a better idea to generate data from a source file or a template than removing certain lines from a file.  It's more robust, less error prone, and tends to work better.

However, if you really want to do this, you can use a smudge/clean filter.  Your smudge command would be `cat` and your clean filter would be `sed -e '/gitignore/,/gitignore/d'`.  If you want a more stringent match, you can adjust the regexes to your taste.

For how to set up a smudge/clean filter, see the `gitattributes(5)` man page.

Comment: This is due to PyCharm using .idea. Due to certainn configurations, it's necessary that I have some lines in xml (and .iml) but not others.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `*.rb inside gitattributes`. It seems that question uses `clean filter`. Suppose the xml file is `foo.xml`.

Create `.gitattributes` and specify the filter for `foo.xml`:

```
echo 'foo.xml filter=removeignore' >> .gitattributes
git add gitattributes
git commit
```

You can name `removeignore` whatever else. And then specify the clean filter of `removeignore`:

```
git config filter.removeignore.clean 'sed -n -e "/<!--/, /<!--/!p"'
```

The `sed` command prints the lines that are not between the lines starting with `<!--`. Add and commit `foo.xml`.

```
git add foo.xml
git commit
```

It's a bit confusing here. Now the clean filter should have been working, but if you open `foo.xml`, you'll see that the expected-to-be-removed lines are still there. In fact, the clean filter works. `git show HEAD:foo.xml` prints the cleaned version, which means the committed version does exclude the lines between `<!--`. Another proof is to clone the current repository into another local repository and you'll find the new repository has the cleaned version of `foo.xml`, with `git clone path/to/current/repository -b <branch> -- path/to/another/folder`. The expected-to-be-removed lines are kept in the current repository, so that they can work as comments. New edits between `<!--` will not be committed. If you want to remove them from the current repository, use `rm foo.xml && git reset --hard`. Note that `git reset --hard` discards all uncommitted changes. If you have other uncommitted changes, stash or commit them first.

The clean filter here works only for the example in your question. If your real case is more complicated, a better way is to write a script that takes a file path for parameter and replace the `sed` command with the script. The script I can think of is a python script that uses `xml.dom.minidom` to accurately parse `foo.xml`, 
 removes the unwanted lines and outputs the expected lines. Don't forget to make the script executable and add its path to the environ variable `PATH`.